# How to get a filtered value to my server controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got my view -> controller -> route -> server-side controller functions

In the server-side controller, I'm sending text messages and need to include the date. The date isn't properly formatted. It looks like this:

```
Thu Nov 20 2014 18:39:01 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

I can format the date in the view or in the angular controller with a simple filter. Like this:

```
{{dateModelName | date:'shortDate' }}
```

But when I get req.body.dateModelName in the server-side controller, it isn't formatted with the filter. How do I get the formatted value?

Comment: are you using ASP.NET MVC in server side?

Comment: MEAN: MongoDB, Express, Angular, & Node. 100% javascript stack

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse a date before filtering. Here is a working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IW6CrhQ2ZFhtxg7WEiIs?p=preview).

```
$scope.dateModelName = Date.parse("Thu Nov 20 2014 18:39:01 GMT-0600 (CST)");
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your response! So now I can do req.body.dateModelName and it'll be parsed for me, in the right format?

Comment: yes, like $scope.dateModelName = Date.parse(req.body.dateModelName); it works, then accept this as a answer.

Comment: I appreciate your support, Asik. How would I format the date to be more easy to read, such as using a filter? When the user hits 'submit', I'd like the value of date to be easier to read.

Comment: its upto you...anyway, medium date is better one{{dateModelName | date:'mediumDate' }} (e.g. Sep 3, 2010) ... you can check the other formats here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date